# How to get disk usage from inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I have started my container using the `--privileged` flag, so as far as I know, all disks should be available from inside the container - and that is partly true, but I somehow can't read the size of them.

`lsblk` on host (Ubuntu):

```
sda                     8:0    1  59,6G  0 disk  
└─sda1                  8:1    1  59,6G  0 part  /media/mauz/ESD-ISO
nvme0n1               259:0    0 953,9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3           259:3    0 952,7G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt   253:0    0 952,6G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 930,4G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

`lsblk` in container (Alpine):

```
sda           8:0    1  59.6G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    1  59.6G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   732M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 952.7G  0 part
```

Both outputs are stripped from `loop` devices, but as you can see, there are 2 drives recognized in both.

Now, if I run the `df` command on the host:

```
Filesystem                1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                       3261580      2564   3259016   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root 959200352 137078032 773327904  16% /
tmpfs                      16307884    215740  16092144   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2               721392    364788    304140  55% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1               523248     76232    447016  15% /boot/efi
tmpfs                       3261576       140   3261436   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1                  62519040  23118848  39400192  37% /media/mauz/ESD-ISO
```

And inside the container:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay              959200352 137078188 773327748  15% /
tmpfs                    65536         0     65536   0% /dev
shm                      65536         0     65536   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
                     959200352 137078188 773327748  15% /app
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
                     959200352 137078188 773327748  15% /etc/os-release
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
                     959200352 137078188 773327748  15% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
                     959200352 137078188 773327748  15% /etc/hostname
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
                     959200352 137078188 773327748  15% /etc/hosts
```

Somehow, it does not show the correct drives in the second `df` output. Is there any way to make `df` show the correct output, even inside the container?

Or is there another way to get the correct disk sizes and usages from the host?

Comment: Ok, well, how do I make them the same? `/dev/sda` is mounted as it seems (lsblk), just df does not do anything with it. If you actually know something, it would be great if you could elaborate. @Philippe

Comment: How can I read disk sizes of unmounted drives then? I need the size of all disks, because I am developing some kind of dashboard that monitors the resources on a single node. It's an open source project, so ease of install is one of the big selling points - that's why it needs to be dockerized. @Philippe

Comment: It may not be the best for this type of application, but it is the only viable for its use-case, so I will be doing it with docker either way. For now, I am passing all mounted volumes manually, but I would like a cleaner solution. @Philippe

Comment: Everything that adds too much overhead is not viable, so unfortunately this is not a good solution for my problem @Philippe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "decent" solution that can accomplish what you want, but let me explain why.

You talk about "disk usage", but in reality there is no such thing as *disk* usage. As far as the disk (i.e. the device itself) is concerned, there is no concept of "usage". What you are looking for is rather *filesystem disk usage*, which is an abstraction and represents a more complex concept.

In order to know the "used" and "available" space of a filesystem, you will have to mount it. This allows the kernel to process filesystem metadata that can then be used to determine free and used filesystem blocks. Without mounting the filesystem this information is simply not available to the kernel (and therefore not available to `df`, for example).

In order for Docker to work, containers run with a different [mount namsepace](https://manned.org/mount_namespaces.7) than the host. The core reason for this is that containers cannot in general safely share mount points with the host. Think for example what would happen if `/` in the host and `/` in the container referred to the same mount point: as soon as the container starts, it would likely break your system by touching sensitive files that it is not supposed to. So by default, Docker will "isolate" containers in their own mount namespace, so that they will only see the mount points they need, and there is no option to avoid this because of the above.

---

You could be able to get this information by reading raw data from the available block devices (without mounting them) and parsing the filesystem metadata (if any) from userspace within the container using some specialized tool, but this is a finicky solution as it would basically require one tool per possible filesystem type. See also [Free space in unmounted partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395949/272806) at Unix & Linux SE.

You could also use [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) allowing the host and the container to share mount points, but this would have to be done on a per-mount basis, for example:

```
docker run --mount readonly,type=bind,source=/media/mauz/ESD-ISO,target=/container/path ...
$ df
...
/dev/sda1                  62519040  23118848  39400192  37% /container/path
...
```

You say that for now you are *"passing all mounted volumes manually"*, so I assume this is not different than whatever you are currently doing. On top of being pretty ugly, this solution would also have the limit of not being able to handle changes in devices or mount points on the host (e.g. if a new device is added and mounted).

---

The only "real" solution I can see here would be to run some application on the host, which periodically extracts the needed information and communicates it to the application running inside the container.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I have already thought about using tools to read unmounted disks, but I haven't even been able to find some for each type of fs-type. Your second suggestion is basically what I am doing right now. I instruct my users to use `-v /mnt:/mnt/host_mnt:ro` and `-v /media:/mnt/host_media:ro` to handle the most common mount points (not 100% sure on that), but as you said it is not very consistent, because if the user decides to mount devices somewhere else, they will not be shown. But I think an application on the host is even uglier, though.

Comment: If no more answers come in, I will award you the bounty, because it really does seam a bit impossible.

Comment: @MauriceNino well, depending on the use case it could make sense to tell the users "this tool will only monitor the volumes that you choose before starting it and will not monitor newly mounted volumes" or something like that, so your current solution could still make sense.

Comment: Yep, that is what I am doing right now. Quote "The volume mounts on `/media:/mnt/host_media:ro` and `/mnt:/mnt/host_mnt:ro` are needed to read the usage stats of all drives. If your drives are mounted somewhere else, you need to pass that drive path with the following format: `-v /{path}:/mnt/host_{path}:ro`."

Answer (score 2):

Using nsenter, this command should achieve what you wanted :

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid host ubuntu nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i bash

# --privileged : run privileged
# --pid host   : shares host's process id namespace

# nsenter - run program with namespaces of other processes
# -t 1        : Specify process 1 to get contexts from
# -m -u -n -i : Share mount, UTS, network, IPC namespace.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to use `-m`? Or what do I need UTS, network and IPC for?

Comment: I put other flags thinking you may be monitoring other resources than the mounts.

Comment: Yeah I am - just trying to understand what you are doing. When I execute this in my container, and then do `ls`, I see all the files of the host. But then I can not execute my application anymore. Is there any way to mount the host into the application context?

Comment: e.g. with network I am doing `nsenter --net=/mnt/host_ns_net mount -t sysfs nodevice /internal_mnt/host_sys` (for clarification: `/mnt/host_ns_net` = `/proc/1/ns/net` on host) - I tried to do the same with your command, but it does not work (`nsenter -t 1 -m mount -t sysfs nodevice /internal_mnt/host_storage`).

Comment: `-t` takes a single argument which is a process id, so you cannot do `-t sysfs`. I know that the command will allow you to do `df` as if you are on the host. I don't know what your application is doing exactly.

Comment: Sorry, but my knowledge of Linux and its commands is really lacking. I would need a way to access the result of df from inside my application. There is nothing fancy going on in my application, it just needs to be in the same context (if that makes sense?).

Comment: You need to put more details of your app and how it behaved, so that others can help.

Comment: I am sorry, you are totally right. I didn't think the context was needed, but I realized it was. Would your command still somehow work if it should run in the same context as some node.js app?

Comment: Above command should work, try to build your node.js app and run it.

Comment: But then I will be stuck in the host namespace. Can I mount the host namespace to my local one, similar to the command I am using for networking right now?

Comment: Now your need is quite different from the current post. Maybe create a new post.

Comment: The thing is - what I am asking now is just a small layer above the current question - I didn't think it would be a problem. But I only got 2 answers here (with a bounty), so I don't think I will get an answer on another question.